# What is SRUJet?

Tags: windows, windows-8, event-log, error-logging

I see in Event log many error entries  :

> svchost (1500) **SRUJet**: An attempt to open the file
>   **"C:\Windows\system32\SRU\SRUDB.dat"** for read / write access failed
>   with system error 5 (0x00000005): **"Access is denied. "**.  The open file
>   operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).

The key in the event log is **ESENT** : `ESENT 490 error`

I already made that error to disappear by setting `Everyone - full control` to the `C:\Windows\system32\SRU\` folder....

But :

**Question**

1) What is `SRUJet` ?
2) What's the purpose of the  `C:\Windows\system32\SRU\` folder  ?
3) What is `ESENT`?

Comment: ESENT is the [Extensible Storage Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961824.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

**SRUJet** is a database engine working with database file **srudb.dat**.

[This thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-getting-event-ids-477-465-481-and-454/7d9c0254-a966-44d3-9a53-1d5d4b135ee3) shows that:

- You should be safely able to delete **srudb.dat** and Windows should re-create it.
- The functionality is part of **Diagnostic Policy Service**.

You can post permissions of the file for further details.

Answer (score 4):

Stop the Diagnostic Policy Service and delete srudb.dat. Worked for me.

To stop the Diagnostic Policy Service: <kbd>[image]</kbd> + R -> Type in `services.msc` -> press Enter -> Scroll down and double-click on Diagnostic Policy Service -> Click the Stop button.

Answer (score 4):

> 3) What is ESENT?

ESENT is the Windows "Extensible Storage Engine" runtime, and is essentially a data store creator for applications such as Desktop Search. In the context of your question, ESENT is used by the Diagnostic Policy Service to build the srudb.dat data file.