# SSD reporting 100GB written per day

Tags: ssd

Just throwing it here in case someone has encountered something similar. These two snapshots are less than 20h apart. My PC stays always on, but I am not aware of any application that would write data all the time.

Yesterday :
[image]

Today:
[image]

[image]

I tried cloning my OS on another SSD and same thing is still happening. Windows 10 x64, Build 18362. Power plan set to High Performance, but Hard disk turned off after 120min. Can anyone suggest a cause?

EDIT. There is a lot of writes from symantec, but other users have the same version installed and no problems:

[image]

The other notable writes are from explorer :

[image]

and svchost pid 12384 C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork -p DPS

[image]

Comment: Try Resource Monitor -> Disk tab. Check if there is something strange there.

Comment: Use [Sysinternals ProcessMonitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to filter disk activity with write operations. May be you have a lot of applications logging all the time something. As each log write writes at least the page size (8KB) of your SSD TBW increases much more faster that actual data is written to the log files.

Comment: I am editing the question to add a process monitor screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using Windows.

The NT kernel is designed as being disk-backed, with the actual RAM only working as a cache to this. This implies, that a lot of disk activity happens on workloads, that are not disk-intensive per se but memory-intensve.

You can reduce the NT swap file(s) to as little as possible, but be advised that there are workloads where not using disk backing will actually reduce performance.

Comment: Hi, can you link to information on where you change this. It rings a bell, but I am not sure. My paging file is 0MB

Comment: That’s too oversimplified a view. Most of the time, the page file is only used to back memory commitments, not actually written to.

Comment: Your quote of "most of the time" holds the answer - it is the reason why we are not talking Terabytes but only 100 Gigs

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, can you link to information on where you change this.

System Properties > Advanced > Performance Options > Advanced > Virtual Memory > Change

See the image linked.  Sorry, not enough reputation to comment on @eugen-riek's answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D57M.png)

Comment: Thx, but i have "No paging file" set there

Comment: Based on ProcMon, you could explore the [SRUjet](https://superuser.com/questions/805336/what-is-srujet) discussed here.