# SRUDB.dat more than 20G

Tags: windows-10

On my win10 system I've noticed that there is one huge file on my HD - SRUDB.dat.

1. Can anybody explain what is this file?
2. Googling, it seems that I can't delete it just like that. How to decrease its size?

Regards

Comment: Try this page, Windows 10 Forums, The first answer should help. https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/78769-anyone-else-have-srudb-dat-error-all-time.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/805336/what-is-srujet